# Flash Action Script 3 function scope

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scope

```
go_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getPlayerName);

var playerName;
function getPlayerName(e:MouseEvent)
{
    playerName = playerName_txt.text;
}

trace(playerName);
```

Hi, is there any way to have this work. I want to update a variable outside the scope of the function.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. Is this code in a class? why can't you access playerName?

Comment: @liranuna: so it isn't in a class?

Comment: make playerName a class member???

Comment: @SP, @Jestro: In this case it's possible, but there are many cases it's just not possible. I am tempted into editing the code example to a better one.

Comment: @LiraNuna: Yeah please give us an example.

Comment: What's going wrong? This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code into a class, instead of a blob of code on a frame or on a MovieClip. All methods inside a class have easy access to any member variables defined on that class.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a value outside of the function, then change it inside the function:

```
go_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getPlayerName);

var playerName:String;
playerName = "nono";
playerName_txt.text = "blah";

function getPlayerName(e:MouseEvent)
{
    playerName = playerName_txt.text;

}

trace(playerName);
```